# Lerp did not translate but directly move the object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am simply want to move an object from **A** to **B** using `Lerp`, but somehow `Lerp` just moves the object directly without any translation. I try to use the `Vector3.Lerp` and another code from YouTube, this is my first time working with `Lerp` please if anyone can help me it is appreciated.
FYI I am using Unity **2019.2.13f** if that is of any use

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class LerpTesting : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private bool shouldLerp = false;

        public Vector2 startPosition;
        public Vector2 endPosittion;

        public float timeStartedLerping;
        public float lerpTime;

        void StartLerping()
        {
            timeStartedLerping = Time.time;
            shouldLerp = true;
        }
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            if(shouldLerp)
            {
                transform.position = Lerp(startPosition, endPosittion, timeStartedLerping, lerpTime);
            }
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            this.gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosittion, 5);
        }

        public Vector3 Lerp(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, float timeStartLerping, float lerptime = 1)
        {
            float timeSinceStarted = Time.time - timeStartLerping;
            float percentageComplete = timeSinceStarted / lerptime;
            var result = Vector3.Lerp(start, end, percentageComplete);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're using Unity's standart Vector3.Lerp in your Update() method. Looks like you want to use your own, so fix Update() with this.gameObject.transform.position = this.Lerp(startPosition, endPosittion, 5);

Comment: Also look into [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) .. you don't want an `Update` running all the time while most of the time it does nothing then causing overhead ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `this.gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosittion, 5);`

You have a constant interpolant of `5`, which is why it immediately jumps to `endPosition`. This value needs to be variable. From what I can tell from your code, this should be `lerpTime`, however this value isn't actually updated in `Update()`, meaning the object would just stay still.

Additionally, since you say you copied some code, I am guessing the intention of the author was for you to use `Lerp` instead of `Vector3.Lerp`. Thus, your `Update()` function should probably look something like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (shouldLerp)
    {
        transform.position = Lerp(startPosition, endPosittion, timeStartedLerping, lerpTime);

        // I'm not 100% sure how lerpTime is supposed to be used,
        // but I'm guessing it's something like this.
        // Either way, this value needs to be updated somehow.
        lerpTime += Time.time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Additionally the factor is always clamped to a value between `0` and `1` so anything higher then `1` returns the `endPosition`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to use lerp in update. Do it in a Coroutine. Remember to yield return new WaitforEndofFrame. Then lerp how much you want.